# How to implement TNM Staging with jquery.inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I am trying to implement a complex mask with several alternate masks
"T(i)|(t)|(4[d])|(1[j])|(1[c])N"

```
T1aN
T1miN
T1N
```

Those are 3 possible values with begining with `T1`. But it fails when `T1` is typed.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0pyce1g/1/).

```
mask: [
  "[p]T(i)|(t)|(4[d])|(1[j])|(1[c])N(n)|(2[c])|(3[c])M(m)|(1[b])[sGg]",

],
//TNM Staging
//T: X, 0, is, 1, 1mi, 1a, 1b, 1c, 2, 3, 4, 4a, 4b, 4c, 4d
//N: X, 0, 1, 1mi, 1a, 1b, 1c, 2, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3, 3a, 3b, 3c,
//M: X, 0, o(i+), 1, 1a, 1b
// eg Tx N1mi M0
```

I am following [RobinHerbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).